# Issue building C++ application in multiarch using Gitea/GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, workflow, multi-arch

I'm trying to create a workflow to build an application in multiple arch (`x86_64`, `i386` and `armv7` for the moment), and build linux package for the target OS. Since the project that will use this workflow depends on other libraries from the target OS, I'm using a docker image for this purpose.

Here is the working workflow for `x86_64` which is the arch the self-hosted docker is running on :

```
name: Build CPP software package

on:
  push

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: https://github.com/actions/checkout@v3

          - name: Build
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  # Install required package for development tools (gcc/g++)
                  slackpkg update
                  
                  slackpkg install gcc gcc-g++ libmpc binutils glibc glibc-solibs
                  slackpkg install cmake libarchive libxml2 cyrus-sasl lzo
                  slackpkg install make guile gc libffi nettle
                  
                  # Build project
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  mkdir build
                  cd build
                  CC="gcc" CXX="g++" cmake ..
                  make all
                                    
          - name: Test
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  cd build
                  ./TestApplicationCPP
```

Here is the modified version working for `armv7` using QEMU :

```
name: Build CPP software package

on:
  push

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: https://github.com/actions/checkout@v3
           
           # Necessary for QEMU
          - name: Setup Docker
            uses: https://github.com/papodaca/install-docker-action@main
          
           # Necessary for arm
          - name: Setup QEMU
            uses: https://github.com/docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
          
          - name: Build
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --platform=linux/arm/v5 --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  # Install required package for development tools (gcc/g++)
                  slackpkg update
                  
                  slackpkg install gcc gcc-g++ libmpc binutils glibc glibc-solibs
                  slackpkg install cmake libarchive libxml2 cyrus-sasl lzo
                  slackpkg install make guile gc libffi nettle
                  
                  # Build project
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  mkdir build
                  cd build
                  CC="gcc" CXX="g++" cmake ..
                  #TODO : Debug make -j {nproc} all
                  make all
                                    
          - name: Test
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --platform=linux/arm/v5 --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  cd build
                  ./TestApplicationCPP
```

And here is the `x86` version that is working :

```
name: Build CPP software package

on:
  push

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: https://github.com/actions/checkout@v3

          - name: Build
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --platform=linux/i386 --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  # Install required package for development tools (gcc/g++)
                  slackpkg update
                  
                  linux32 slackpkg install gcc gcc-g++ libmpc binutils glibc glibc-solibs
                  linux32 slackpkg install cmake libarchive libxml2 cyrus-sasl lzo
                  linux32 slackpkg install make guile gc libffi nettle
                  
                  # Build project
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  mkdir build
                  cd build
                  CC="gcc" CXX="g++" linux32 cmake ..
                  linux32 make all
                                    
          - name: Test
            uses: https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
              image: aclemons/slackware:14.2
              options: --platform=linux/i386 --volumes-from=${{ env.JOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}
              run: |
                  cd ${{ github.workspace }}
                  cd build
                  ./TestApplicationCPP
```

So now I'm wondering first if it is possible to get rid of the `linux32` prefix in 32bits mode? It is required for the workflow to work, otherwise `uname -m` return `x86_64` which is host arch, and it causes `slackpkg` to try to find packages with this arch. It will also cause issues elsewhere. So I would like a more elegent solution.

The second thing, I would prefer to have all those three workflows be identical so they could be put into a matrix I suppose.